# Avoiding NullReferenceException in Request.QueryString

Tags: c#, asp.net, query-string, nullreferenceexception

This code throws a `NullReferenceException` if `mode` is not specified in the pages query string:

```
bool isAdvancedMode = Request.QueryString["mode"].Equals("advanced");
```

This is how I work around this:

```
bool isAdvancedMode = (Request.QueryString["mode"] + "").Equals("advanced");
```

Is this standard practise, or a hack?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [null-coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx):

```
bool isAdvancedMode = (Request.QueryString["mode"] ?? String.Empty).Equals("advanced");
```

**Edit:** If you want to re-use this logic, try this extension method:

```
public static bool EqualIfExists(this string source, string comparison)
{
    return source != null && source.Equals(comparison);
}

Request.QueryString["mode"].EqualIfExists("advanced")
```

Add more overrides to match `Equals` signature. I'm not sure if this is a good name (I think it is not).

Comment: Nice. We'll see which one he picks!

Comment: Ahah. Last time @newStackExchangeInstance and I (like 30 minutes ago) answered the same questions 30 seconds apart, I won. I feel this one should go to him. So +1 to him. ;)

Comment: Thanks for answers, think this one goes to Simon as he was first to answer!

Answer (score 4):

Well, I would recommend this instead:

```
bool isAdvancedMode = (Request.QueryString["mode"] ?? "").Equals("advanced");
```

In fact, this is what [your code compiles to](http://ericlippert.com/2013/06/17/string-concatenation-behind-the-scenes-part-one/) (Nearer the bottom, but it's a good read so I'd read it all). Yours is good practice, but this is a bit more clear.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use the null coalescing operator?

```
bool isAdvancedMode = (Request.QueryString["mode"] ?? String.Empty).Equals("advanced");
```

Comment: Well, actually, it compiles to the same code. Don't believe me? http://ericlippert.com/2013/06/17/string-concatenation-behind-the-scenes-part-one/

Comment: I wasn't saying that it doesn't, just stating that the null-coalescing operator is more readable.

Comment: I know, just interesting fact of the day :)

Answer (score 0):

Different approach, while a bit more code, I think is more clear the intent.

```
bool isAdvancedMode = String.IsNullOrWhitespace(Request.QueryString["mode"]) ? 
                        false : Request.QueryString["mode"].Equals("advanced")
```

Comment: While this is good, It feels dirty to me to access a dictionary value twice (even though it's _O(1)_ in most cases). Also, it could be reduced to `!String.IsNullOrWhitespace(Request.QueryString["mode"]) && Request.QueryString["mode"].Equals("advanced")`

Comment: @SimonBelanger good point about dictionary access, in that case I would use your ?? method myself too :)

Answer (score 0):

what about this

```
bool isAdvancedMode=(Request.QueryString["mode"] ?? string.Empty).Equals("advanced");
```

Comment: Looking for a one liner really as this problem is a common occurance